# Shopify How to Display Stock Quantity on low stock products

Tags: ruby, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-activemerchant, shopify-template

Shopify How to  Display Stock Quantity on low stock products

I did something like

```
 {% for variant in product.variants %}

          {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
        {%  assign stocklevel = variant.inventory_quantity %}

{% if stocklevel < 10 %}
{% variant.inventory_quantity%}
  {% endif %} 



           {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

but it only displayed the first variant value

I

Comment: Do you need to get stock only for first available variant or for each variant of the product?

Comment: Why is that `if` statement there? Isn’t that only showing low stock for the first variant? Try removing it